# How to get the point to line segment distance in 2D?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I’m just wondering if there is a simple way to get the distance between a point and a line segment in 2D in Matlab?

Comment: what's your definition of "line segment"?

Comment: The line segment basically composes of two points, A (x1, y1) B (x2, y2)

Comment: What do you mean with "simple way in matlab"? This is a basic math question, where you can put your pen&paper result in one line of code. These questions are kind of off-topic here.

Comment: by simple way he means a built in function or a one line solution (which was not given here)

Comment: `distance=abs((p2(1)-p1(1))*(p1(2)-p3(2)) - (p1(1)-p3(1))*(p2(2)-p1(2)))/norm(p1-p2);` where `p1, p2` - points of line, example `p1=[2, 5]`, ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = [0,0]; %some point
a = [1,2]; %segment points a,b
b = [3,5];

d_ab = norm(a-b);
d_ax = norm(a-x);
d_bx = norm(b-x);

if dot(a-b,x-b)*dot(b-a,x-a)>=0
    A = [a,1;b,1;x,1];
    dist = abs(det(A))/d_ab;        
else
    dist = min(d_ax, d_bx);
end
```